# How to PHP server-side check if a url of a web site is valid?

Tags: php, validation, url, server-side

I've searched our SO questions but found solutions are based on calling `ping` command executed from using `system` PHP function.

My web host server doesn't allow me to do that. What should I do?

Please help,
Nam.

*Update*

I need to check from the `server side`.

Comment: More context would help find a good solution. What is your exact use case for this? What do you need to validate the URL for? Does the URL need to be reachable, or just valid?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If by a valid URL you mean one which does not 404, then you could use [`get_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) and look for `404` in the first returned array element.

```
$url = 'http://google.com';
list($status) = get_headers($url);
if (strpos($status, '404') !== FALSE) {
   // URL is 404ing
}
```

Alternatively, you could look for `200` which would be a normal happy request :)

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
//checking if the site exists by fopen, instead of file_get_contents to speed it up

$url = "URL"; //your url goes in this place instead of nabtron.com

if (@fopen($url,"r")) {
echo "<b>".$url."</b> is accessible<br />";
}
```