# Composer Install "Failed to open stream"

Tags: php, composer-php, laragon

Whenever I run the installer, or even manually installing Composer, I get an error that disallowed me to complete the installation and it is irritating. In Laragon, a program used to create many different projects using composer and its packages. It will not allow me to use Laravel because the Composer will not properly install and function.

The **Error** is:

> The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded:
>   failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond.
>
> The "https://getcomposer.org/download/1.4.2/composer.phar.sig" file
>   could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond.

Comment: could you add output of "composer diagnose"? update: sorry I didnt noticed that you cant Install it

Comment: are you using linux or windows?

Comment: @RafailAkhmetshin I am using windows, the strange thing is I can use composer diagnose but composer isn't installing... I guess because I am Using Laragon which comes with composer

Comment: And does composer diagnose give you any warning about failed tests? could you check that url is accessible from php using hints from this answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764002/how-to-php-server-side-check-if-a-url-of-a-web-site-is-valid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030789/pinging-an-ip-address-using-php-and-echoing-the-result

Comment: @RafailAkhmetshin It says the websites are dead. Also, I have the diagnose composer errors but I am not sure where to post it. I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: @RafailAkhmetshin Nevermind, here you go: https://pastebin.com/NGk0YxKK

Comment: are you trying to do this in corporate network or at home? Could you try to connect to https url (important) using curl or something like it ```curl https://getcomposer.org/versions``` Also can you check that your openssl extension is enabled? in php.ini

Comment: So, after a lot of time being frustrated (home network), I tried a VPN and it worked, so how can I do this without a VPN? @RafailAkhmetshin

Comment: I don't know. We need figure out what was blocked when you use home network. could you open ```https://getcomposer.org/versions``` using your browser or do you receive any king warnings about certificate?

Comment: No warning, it shows this: {
    "stable": [{"path": "/download/1.4.2/composer.phar", "version": "1.4.2", "min-php": 50300}],
    "preview": [{"path": "/download/1.4.2/composer.phar", "version": "1.4.2", "min-php": 50300}],
    "snapshot": [{"path": "/composer.phar", "version": "189ba423aedc387a0487df40afc2428947406327", "min-php": 50300}]
} @RafailAkhmetshin

Comment: Also, the curl getcomposer.org line works and produces the proper line. Although, curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php resulted in an error while downloading... The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: So, I just tried install and use composer on my laptop and it worked, so it is something to do with my PC, that is weird, anything I should do to fix this? @RafailAkhmetshin

Comment: could you add output of this command ```php -i | grep " PHP Stream"```. also please check to this issue - looks very similar to yours https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4888

Comment: 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. I tried to clean my ipv6 but it didn't fix. @RafailAkhmetshin

Answer (score 4):

**Understand that the error is an IPV6 network error**

- At first, I updated the version of my composer running this command

  composer -vvv self-update
- I also followed this instruction from composer doc on resolving IPV6 timed out issue

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#operation-timed-out-ipv6-issues-

*I can't say which of these did the magic*

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the **https_proxy** and **http_proxy** environment vars worked for me (Windows 10). And then installing it, set proxy in blank. It should work as it did for me.