# laravel version 6.0 does not include the vuejs file assets/components,App.vue, inside resources/js folder. This is why and how to fix it?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

After the laravel version 6.0 release, when i install the fresh laravel application it does not include the `vue.js` files `assets/components`, App.vue. i don't know how to fix it. I wanna develop a project in the laravel and vue.

`require('./bootstrap');`

this is app.js file and it include only this line of code.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it does not include because that was moved out of the core in a separate package called [laravel/ui](https://github.com/laravel/ui) you can install the package using `composer` and then use the prebuilt components for Authentication for example and whatever else it provides.

And here is the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/frontend) for it.

Comment: @Annuktk you are welcome :) Please accept the answer.

Comment: [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/laravel/ui%24309717cea10da71645b416ac70b9c2dd997cfb
  5cd629536737bbda8ed1119e36.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddres
  ses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is
   known.

Comment: it give error when "i run composer require laravel/ui" this in the root directory of application

Comment: Do you maybe have any network issues? Because I just ran it on my machine and everything worked as intended.

Comment: i don't think so, i have an internet connection that works good.

Comment: You have issues with your composer my friend. Take a look [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4388) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53986012/getting-error-while-installing-laravel-installer-in-window-10) for example. It is not related to this question anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As @nakov said, Vue is now moved to larvel/ui package. To install it , you have to run `composer require laravel/ui` command in your project directory.
Then run `php artisan ui vue` command then run `npm install && npm run dev` . 
Now you can see that there is vue component in your app.js .