# Laravel Composer Error: Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, composer-php

I'm actually new to Laravel and I'm working with Laravel 5.8 to develop my project.

Basically I wanted to check the file `ExampleComponent.vue` at `resources/js/components` directory but it wasn't there so as this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57843133/laravel-version-6-0-does-not-include-the-vuejs-file-assets-components-app-vue-i) says, I have to run `composer require laravel/ui` command and after that, `php artisan ui vue` command, then `npm install && npm run dev`.

But I typed the first command which is `composer require laravel/ui` and it suddenly said:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - laravel/ui 2.x-dev requires illuminate/support ^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[7.x-dev, 8.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.22.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.26.0, v7.26.1, v7.27.0, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - laravel/ui v2.2.0 requires illuminate/support ^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[7.x-dev, 8.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.22.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.26.0, v7.26.1, v7.27.0, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - don't install illuminate/support 7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support 8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support 8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.10.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.10.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.10.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.10.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.11.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.12.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.13.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.14.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.14.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.15.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.16.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.16.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.17.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.17.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.17.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.18.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.19.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.19.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.2.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.2.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.20.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.21.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.22.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.22.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.22.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.22.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.22.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.23.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.23.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.23.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.24.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.25.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.26.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.26.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.27.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.5.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.8.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.9.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.9.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.9.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.8.38, required as 5.8.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.38].
    - Installation request for laravel/ui ^2.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[2.x-dev, v2.2.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

So I don't know what to do now, would you please help me out with this?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you need Laravel 7+ for laravel/ui. Seems you are using 5.8

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with your laravel version, which is old for latest `laravel/ui` Project.

Try with a fresh project:

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` For new project, replace your project name with `blog`, then try `composer require laravel/ui` to add `vue/react/angular` scaffolds.

Also I'm suggesting to do a new project since you said you're new to laravel and you should keep your project and libraries up to date.

Full Laravel Installation Documents [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation)

Edit:

If you don't want to create a new project you can simply, edit your `composer.json` in project and change these lines to the latest versions or just replace parts with below:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.24",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
 }
```

Then simply run `Composer update`, ofc there are some big changes to take care since you're using 5.* but this is where you should start to just simply include new `ui` library to project.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is explained by the following two lines:

```
- laravel/ui 2.x-dev requires illuminate/support ^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[7.x-dev, 8.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.22.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.26.0, v7.26.1, v7.27.0, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
- laravel/ui v2.2.0 requires illuminate/support ^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[7.x-dev, 8.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.22.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.26.0, v7.26.1, v7.27.0, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
```

To install `laravel/ui` 2.x, you need to have `illuminate/support` 7.x or 8.x, which corresponds to `laravel/framework` 7.x or 8.x.

To make it work with your version of laravel (5.8), you need to find a version of that library that does work with that version of laravel. If you go to packagist, you can browse [all versions of `laravel/ui`](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/ui), and it turns out that 1.2.0 does support laravel 5.8. You can thus solve your problem by installing an earlier version `composer require laravel/ui:1.2.0`. Note that this version might or might not contain the functionality you seek though. If you have the option of upgrading laravel instead, that is probably the better option.

Comment: You can just update your laravel without starting a new project. Just follow the migration guides for [laravel 6.x](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade) and [laravel 7.x](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade).

Answer (score 0):

You installed laravel/ui version 3.0 which corresponds laravel 8.x.
you should install ui 2.x version with this command:

```
composer require laravel/ui:2.x
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 6 run the commands:

```
composer require laravel/ui "2.x"

php artisan ui vue --auth

npm install && npm run dev
```