# check if a url is reachable, always returning false

Tags: php

My problem is that it returns an error for every url entered:

The below code takes and checks the url entered, if i enter 'http://eample.com' it would return success but for some reason it returns all urls as unreachable.

```
<?php
Global $excludeLocal;
$excludeLocal = true; // Whether to exclude checking links on the same host as the plugin resides

// Hook our custom function into the 'shunt_add_new_link' filter
 yourls_add_filter( 'shunt_add_new_link', 'churl_reachability' );

// Add a new link in the DB, either with custom keyword, or find one
function churl_reachability( $churl_reachable, $url, $keyword = '' )     {
   global $ydb, $excludeLocal;

// Check if the long URL is a different type of link
$different_urls = array (
    array ( 'mailto://', 9 ),
    array ( 'ftp://', 6 ),
    array ( 'javascript://', 13),
    array ( 'file://', 7 ),
    array ( 'telnet://', 9),
    array ( 'ssh://', 6),
    array ( 'sip://', 6),
    );

foreach ($different_urls as $url_type){
    if (substr( $url, 0, $url_type[1] ) == $url_type[0]){
        $churl_reachable = true; // No need to check reachability if URL type is different
        break;
    } elseif ($excludeLocal) {
        if (substr($url, 0, strlen('http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) == 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
            $churl_reachable = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Check if the long URL is a mailto
if ($churl_reachable == false){
    $churl_reachable = churl_url_exists( $url );  // To do: figure out how to use yourls_get_remote_content( $url ) instead.
}

// Return error if the entered URL is unreachable
if ( $churl_reachable == false ){
    $return['status']   = 'fail';
    $return['code']     = 'error:url';
    $return['message']  = 'The entered URL is unreachable.  Check the URL or try again later.';
    $return['statusCode'] = 200; // regardless of result, this is still a valid request
    return yourls_apply_filter( 'add_new_link_fail_unreachable', $return, $url, $keyword, $title );
} else {
    return false;
   }
 }

function churl_url_exists( $churl ){
    $handle = @fopen($churl, "r");
    if ($handle === false)
        return false;
        fclose($handle);
        return true;
   }
```

is there something i might have did wrong ?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764002/how-to-php-server-side-check-if-a-url-of-a-web-site-is-valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check `allow_url_fopen` directive in your php.ini

Try to run the command `$handle = fopen($churl, "r");` without a `@` symbol and see the error